# Naivgate tabs by url HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Let's say I have this `ul` which filters a grid of items based on `data-filter`:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="l1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="l2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="l3">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="l4">Link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

When entering the url like this: [www.something.com/#l1](http://www.something.com/#l1), I want to simulate a click on `Link1`. And when manually clicking on `Link1`, I want to add to the url `/#l1`.

I can use jQuery to add a `$(document).ready()` function, to get the querystring from the URL and clicking with `.click()`. But I have no idea how to change the url when clicking on a `<a>`.

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Use the History API to change the URL without navigating.

Comment: what you have tried so far? post a minimal reproducible example